# Select points North of line across polygon using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, select

[image]I need to select all points north of a line. I'm have trouble conceptualizing what tools would allow me to do this. Any advice? I'm in ArcGIS 10.2.2 if that matters.

In the poorly drawn picture I would like to select all red points north of the green line. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please make your question clearer? Is this a straight line? Should the calculation consider all points north of the line? Just points which area at a higher latitude for the north most point along the line?

Comment: Please draw a picture to show what you mean. By north do you mean "y" value greater or do you need to adjust for true/magnetic north and (possibly) projection?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I have a map with the state of Louisiana. I also have a number of points which are spread on the map. I'm trying to select all points north of a specific interstate. I'll try to draw a picture now.

Comment: split Loouisianna in 2 polygons by green line. Create spatial join between points and 2 polygons

Comment: That's a good point @FelixIP, also consider Near http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000 with angles... points above will have angles in the 3rd and 4th quadrant where below they should be 1st and 2nd quadrant - the distinction should be quite apparent and succinct. The tool to split the polygon is Feature to Polygon http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003n000000 provide the existing polygon and the line also and it will 'build' to two polygons if there are no gaps in the line.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I appreciate the help. I think using the feature to polygon tool should help me.

Comment: I think your question is really how to select points which are within the northern half of the black polygon when it is split by the green line so, as others have commented, make that polygon by whichever means you prefer and then Select Layer By Location will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This field calculator code (Python) assumes that green line is just a single shape:

```
def Chainage(shp):
 mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
 layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"line")
 lr=layers[0]
 with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr, 'Shape@') as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
   geom=row[0]
 p=shp.firstPoint
 L=geom.queryPointAndDistance (p)
 return L[3]
```

To call it use

```
Chainage( !Shape!)
```

Run it on numeric field (short) in points' table. It will return 0 for points to the left of the line or 1 for points on the right side of it.

Code assumes the name of 'green' line in table of content is 'line'.

[image]